Curves meeting at a tangent and repeated roots
Hey I came across a question where there was two curves, one defined parametrically:
$C_1$: $y=c/t$
,  $x=ct$
$C_2$: $(x-\alpha)^2 +(y-\beta)^2=r^2$
One part of the question relied on the fact that given that the two curves touch at two distinct points, so that they are tangent to each other. And the quartic polynomial $f(t)=t^4-(2\alpha/c)t^3 + ((\alpha^2 +\beta^2-r^2)/c^2)t^2-(2\beta/c)t+1$ has roots which give the t-values for the intersection of the two curves. To solve the question it was needed that the polynomial has repeated roots $t_2$ and $t_1$.
I don't really understand why tangency implies repeated roots i.e. why can't there be two distinct real roots to the polynomial and two complex conjugate roots. Is this true for any two curves that there are always repeated roots of the equation g(x) = h(x) for two functions g and h if they are tangent to each other? And if this is true does it hold both ways?
Thanks

Welcome to MSE. Can you elaborate on the role of the quartic $f(t)$ here?

The quartic has roots that give the parameter values for when the two curves intersect. The quartic could be rewritten to give a quartic in x by using t=x/c which would again result in two repeated roots.

It is true that if $x=c$ is a repeated zero (multiplicity > 1) of $f(x)$ then $f'(c)=0$. Interpret this as a function having a tangent parallel to the $x-$ axis at $x=c$

It is also possible your curves never intersect or are never tangent. It depends on the curves themselves

A common first introduction to tangents to the graph of a function is through thinking about limit of secants. A secant line by definition intersects the curve, corresponding to having a real root of the equation of the line substituted into the equation of the curve. When you have a closed curve the number of roots, counted with multiplicity, is even. Varying the secant line these roots vary and when you get a double root, the, say, $x$-values come together. This need not mean there’s a tangency, since it could be $\langle x, x^2+y^2-1\rangle,$ but when it's $\langle x-1, x^2+y^2-1\rangle,$ it is. You probably guessed, in the first case the $y$-values are different, and in the second they're the same. But these, for curves defined by polynomials and where the curve is smooth, are the only cases.
The presentation of the ideals above can be reduced to $\langle x, (y-1)(y+1)\rangle,$ and $\langle x-1, y^2\rangle.$ A singly tangent tangent is always of the second form. There can be higher order tangencies.
In the generality of current algebraic geometry, there's a slight complication in that a line can be double to start with. This is captured by the same ideal, now interpreted as the double $x$-axis intersecting the line $x=1.$ The result is still a double point. A double line intersecting a curve in the plane picks out the tangent, so this can be taken to locally be the definition of a tangent. I.e. if points correspond to maps from $k$ (map $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ to your (affine) scheme, indeed a $k$-point of a $k$-scheme is defined to be such a map that composes with the structure morphism to the identity), the tangent correspond to a map from the dual numbers $k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2).$ See the exercise 2.8 p. 80 in Hartshorne GTM 52.
